# Can I create a rescue DVD with an image created with Macrium backup

Tags: windows-xp, backup, freeze, macrium

I have installed Macrium software free edition.

I have created an image file 3GB in size. I want to store the rescue media and Image file on ONE DVD.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this would be to create an ISO image first:

[image: ISO Image creation dialog]

This will create an ISO image of the rescue CD environment which can be burnt at a later date. Before you burn it, however, you can add the image to the disk using any ISO editing software, e.g. [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).